# Cant find the app_name in string.xml?

Tags: android

My manifest give me a error

> No resource found that matches the given name at 'label' with value
>   '@string/app_name

but I already declare that in `strings.xml`

Manifest::

```
 <application
            android:label="@string/app_name "
           >
    <activity
                android:name=".authentication.AuthenticatorActivity" android:label="@string/login_label"/>
            <activity
                android:name=".authentication.SignUpActivity" android:label="@string/signup_title" />

            <service android:name=".authentication.UdinicAuthenticatorService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                    android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
            </service>
         </application>
   </manifest>
```

String.xml::

```
 <resources>
        <string name="app_name">AccountAuthenticator</string>
        <string name="label">Udinic</string>
        <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
        <string name="signup_title">Create new account</string>
        <string name="login_label">Log in</string>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Clean your project once.

Comment: Remove space from this @string/app_name . You have extra space in Manifest. In this line android:label="@string/app_name "

Comment: Try to clean project

Comment: Remove that one extra space after `@string/app_name`

Comment: already did that still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove space in both main/manifest and debug/manifest
(android:label="@string/app_name "), i think you are doing with one.
Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Remove space from the line `@string/app_name` . You have extra space in Manifest. In this line `android:label="@string/app_name "`

Comment: already tried that , and after doing that space get back automatically

Answer (score 0):

if removing space in  `android:label="@string/app_name "` doesnt work

then goto your project folder **app/** and delete **build** folder, then 
remove that **space** again and **rebuild** your project.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Removing the space between string and name and type the space again

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Sample_Dao</string>
</resources>
```